# SAPUI5 Minification - real performance boost? / Improve performance on loadup

Tags: performance, sapui5, minify, ui5-tooling

I heard some rumors about minifying SAPUI5 applications to improve Performance, especially that comments should be removed?

Does anyone know something about it? Are there tools especially for UI5 to do this minification?

Any other tips for improving Performance on loadup?

My ideas:

- Require only controls instead of complete libraries

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58694877/5846045 (bundling and minifying only required modules)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [grunt-openui5](https://github.com/SAP/grunt-openui5) to minify your libraries and components.
This merges your files into a single preload file and therefore reduces the number of requests which should improve loading performance.