# Bootstraping OpenUI5 from single JS file

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

OpenUI5 documentation suggests starting work by using a library loaded from CDN:

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.42.6/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.table"></script>
```

Unfortunately, this approach means load cascading 4 scripts on startup:

- sap-ui-core.js
- sap/ui/core/library.js (why ?)
- sap/m/library.js
- sap/ui/table/library.js

Is there way to bundle this four libraries into one script file?

Comment: UI5 is not a simple library like jQuery but a complex framework. Putting all in one file would mean a single file with a size of probably 100 MB or more. This is why controls (e.g. Buttons, Tables, Layouts) are divided into individual libraries. The framework then loads these libraries depending on your needs.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? In reality the browser will be loading more files as well as the above - some may be additional js files. Its not clear what your real concern is - most web pages load a significant number of files including scripts. Could you perhaps clarify further?

Comment: Five necessary files: sap-ui-core.js, sap/ui/core/library-preload.js, sap/m/library-preload.js, sap/ui/table/library-preload.js and sap/ui/unified/library-preload.js have a size 1,28 MB not 100 MB.

Comment: @Bernard Im using webpack and my application has finally only one js and one css file. But OpenUI5 give me additionality 5 http requests.

Comment: Does the answer below help? Or what is missing? I could extend the answer if it's needed

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, this approach means load cascading multiple scripts on startup:

The cascading behavior is mostly due to missing an option that tells the framework to load UI5-libraries and other modules asynchronously. In order to fix it, please add the following attribute too:

```js
data-sap-ui-async="true" // available since 1.58.2 --> Replaces preload="async" *
```

```js
data-sap-ui-preload="async" // for 1.58.1 and below
```

***** Prerequisite: *[Is Your Application Ready for Asynchronous Loading?](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/493a15aa978d4fe9a67ea9407166eb01.html)*

---

> Is there way to bundle these four libraries into one script file?

Yes; with a *self-contained* build (e.g. `ui5 build self-contained --all` ), you can reduce the size of your application as well as number of requests by bundling the required modules into a single file `sap-ui-custom.js`

[image]

In the above screenshot, for example, `sap-ui-custom.js` contains only the required modules from `sap.ui.core`-, `sap.m`-, `sap.ui.table`-, and `sap.ui.unified`-library, in addition to application related resources such as the controllers, views, etc..

See [openui5-sample-app](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-sample-app#option-2-self-contained-build) and the [UI5 tooling](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-tooling) for official documentation.