# how to detect and remove all unused dependencies of openui5

Tags: performance, optimization, sapui5, ui5-tooling

i am working on a openui5 application but i am stuck on How to detect and remove unused openui5 dependencies and themes from resources folder to create a optimize bundle of openui5.
below is my ui5.yaml file

```
    specVersion: '2.6'
metadata:
  name: com.sample.test
type: application
framework:
  name: OpenUI5
  version: "1.101.0"
  libraries:
    - name: sap.ui.core
    - name: sap.tnt
    - name: sap.ui.layout
    - name: sap.m
    - name: sap.f
    - name: sap.ui.table
    - name: themelib_sap_fiori_3
    - name: themelib_sap_bluecrystal
resources:
  configuration:
    paths:
      webapp: public
```

and here is my manifest.json file:

```
    {
    "_version": "1.12.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "public",
        "type": "application"
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.75.0",
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.m": {},
                "sap.f": {},
                "ui5customgrid":{},
                "ui5datemap": {},
                "ui5customdom": {},
                "ui5custommenu": {}
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "css": [
                {
                    "uri": "css/"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/58694877/5846045 help?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann Thanks for the answer i have tried your approach but single file is not very useful because of file size in my case 69 mb is the size of file which is impossible to load for average network one more problem is i am getting some errors while building like "'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType:" and "error: missing module ..."

Comment: did you put the entire sdk under `resources` or something?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann i have added configurations

Comment: @Jorg no i have not added entire sdk under resources

Comment: Are you building the app from SAP Web IDE?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann No i am trying to build openui5 application locally on vscode